# WebDriver isn't launching the ChromeDriver

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am developing a test case using selenium to verify that a user has reached the properties list on a travel site. When i go to run the application on eclipse, the driver is failing.

I have tried using the "WebElement" method as another option but, that is giving me the same issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Extracted Files\\Chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe"); 
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
    driver.get("https://www.booking.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.className("input-location.location-field.px-2")).sendKeys("Krakow, Poland");
    Thread.sleep(2000); 
    driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 submit-search-form")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.close();
}
```

Expected result is to bring up all the listing for the searched area on the properties page. Actual result is the application is simply failing to execute and is highlighting the "WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver" line.

Any help or assistance/documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z'


at selenium.demo.HostelworldTest.main(HostelworldTest.java:33)

Comment: The message is clear, there is a mismatch between ChromeDriver and Chrome browser versions. Upgrade Chrome to version 76 or download another ChromeDriver. You can find the matching versions in https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads.